# Custom Join table in grails

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-orm, join

I have a following domains

1. User (in database called usermanagement) and
2. Account (in another database xyz)

Its an old system so i cannot really change the architecture of the system. I have been assigned task to implement a system that a certain users can only access certain accounts. This is a classic case of many-to-many relationship but the problem lies in the fact that these two domains are in two different databases. I googled if that was possible but i realized that it was not possible. So I now am thinking of creating a custom join table to store info on which user are allowed access to which accounts. The table can have two columns 'accountId' and 'userId'. So for this, do i have to create a new domain in grails or is there any cleaver way of doing this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you create joinTable in which DB you are going to create it and how you are going handle updates in main (Account,User) tables and ceep your join table up2date  ?

I think (for this case) you don't need join table, you need handle business logic in application level.

You cane have 2 Domain classes each one pointed to different dataSource(DataBase).

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources

Comment: yes i have two domain class pointed to two different sources. User table is in usermanagement and Account is in xyz database. The usermanagement is a common database, other apps also use that so i cannot touch that. xyz is my database, so i can put the join table in this database. I need to regulate the access for users

Answer (score 1):

As I searched for solution of this, I did not find any sustainable solutions. I eventually narrowed down the probable solutions to two:
1. Create a domain table (only) using sql, some sort of patch and use hard-coded queries in grails to write and access data to and from the table.
2. Create a domain class like AccountUser having properties clientId and userId

I choose the 2nd option, I wrote some additional methods and created a service to return user and client instance and I am done ! Anyways, thanks guys.

Answer (score -1):

If the databases are "visible" to each other (on the same server or there is a db link between them), you should be able to map the domain classes using the fully qualified table names ('schema.tablename') in the mapping closure.

psuedocode:

```
class User {

static mapping = {
    table "usermanagement.user"
}

static hasMany = [Account:accounts]

}

class Account {

static mapping = {
    table "xyz.account"
}

}
```

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#tableAndColumnNames

Comment: i have already done this, now i need to create a join table between these two.